# Angular Image Zoom Effect

Tags: css, angularjs, image, angularjs-directive, zooming

I am trying to replicate FluidBox jQuery Image zoom effect using angular directives:
http://terrymun.github.io/Fluidbox/demo/index.html

When an image is clicked, it zooms up from inline to an overlay being centered in view.

I have the basics working. But to have an image zoom up, it requires position absolute. And to center absolute positioned element you need margin auto. But margin auto is producing wrong element offsets.

I'm looking for a better approach, as i'm starting to use timeouts and that's not good :)

Here is the image html:

```
<img src="thumb.jpg" data-large="large.jpg" />
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive('img', function($window, $document, $timeout) {

    function matchDimensions(parent, el) {
        var elemRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
        el.css('bottom', elemRect.bottom + 'px');
        el.css('top', elemRect.top + 'px');
        el.css('left', elemRect.left + 'px');
        el.css('right', elemRect.right + 'px');
        el.css('max-height', elemRect.height + 'px');
        el.css('max-width', elemRect.width + 'px');
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var body = $document.find('body')[0],
                expanded = false,
                overlay = angular.element('<div class="overlay"></div>'),
                table = angular.element('<div class="t"></div>'),
                cell = angular.element('<div class="tc"></div>'),
                clone = element.clone(true);

            element.bind('click', function() {
                if (expanded === false) {
                    matchDimensions(element[0], clone);
                    body.appendChild(overlay[0]);
                    $timeout(function() {
                        clone.addClass('expanded');
                        expanded = true;
                    }, 100);
                }
            });

            clone.bind('click', function() {
                if (expanded === true) {
                    expanded = false;
                    matchDimensions(element[0], clone);
                    clone.removeClass('expanded');
                    $timeout(function() {
                        body.removeChild(overlay[0]);
                    }, 500);
                }
            });

            element.addClass('zoom');
            clone.addClass('expand');
            clone.attr('src', attrs.large);
            overlay.append(table);
            table.append(cell);
            cell.append(clone);
        }
    };
});
```

And the css:

```
img.expand {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-property: all;
}

img.expanded {
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
    cursor: zoom-out;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

[JSfiddle using css top and left positions](https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/jwtj57kt/5/)

[JSfiddle using css3 transforms scale and translate](https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/ruwajt2e/4/)

Looking forward for a better approach to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Plugin author commenting. What do you mean by incorrect offsets—are you referring to the incorrect vertical centering seen in your fiddle?

Comment: @Terry yep trying to get the thing centered horizontally and vertically. I have a second version using css3 transforms. Much smoother, but again need to center it! https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/ruwajt2e/4/

Comment: I think this might work: https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/ruwajt2e/5/

Comment: The original plugin performs centering by positioning the image relative to its thumbnail, which involves some complicated calculations about the offsets to make it vertically centered... the calculations are explain in my write up here: https://medium.com/coding-design/presenting-fluidbox-9c7fe9db92c7